# Exchange site about mobile phones and related technology?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I wonder, is there an Exchange site that treats mobile phones and mobile phone technologies in general ? I did a quick check and found there are Exchange sites for Windows phone, Android and Apple. However, I am interested in more general questions about technology, development and industry of the phone area. Discussion and site recommendation please, thank you.

Comment: This fits into StackOverflow-proper . mobile is very much part of it

Comment: Ah , on second read. Geeneral Q's and discussion doesn't fit well into StakcExchange

Comment: Yes Adel, that led me to posting this question here on Meta =)

Comment: @JamesC I don't think the topics you mentioned are specific enough for us to help you.  `general questions about technology, development and industry of the phone area` is not specific enough.  Are you talking hardware, software, Operations Systems, apps, wireless communication standards?  You could be looking at multiple sites or none at all.

Comment: Topics are not specific, but questions would be. And all focused around same area - mobile phone technology. Is it really just me, who feels that having to ask about : operating system, new apps, new technology, repair tips etc... each on a different site would be a waste of knowledge and information ? Because it would be scattered all over ? Every person uses a phone, there are tons of possible topics. And for example, look at SuperUser forum, they discuss computer software, hardware and different OS. Is that considered specific enough, comparing to my suggestion ?

Comment: Hi AI E.
The question you posted asked "Is there any Stack Exchange where i can ask questions about problems of my phone?"
It only partially embraces the entire field. You may see that my question / suggestion has many more topics to talk about.